# Unable to install Warzone2100 due to broken packages

Tags: package-management

I tried using the command `sudo apt install warzone2100` to install Warzone 2100 but I'm getting the error below. Please can anyone advise how to resolve this issue?

```
Laptop@HP-DM1Z:~$ sudo apt install warzone2100
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 warzone2100 : Depends: libglew2.0 (>= 1.12.0) but it is not installable
               Depends: libqt5core5a (>= 5.7.0) but 5.5.1+dfsg-16ubuntu7.5 is to be installed
               Depends: libqt5script5 (>= 5.6.0~beta) but 5.5.1+dfsg-2build1 is to be installed
               Depends: libstdc++6 (>= 6) but 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

EDIT: I am currently using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

If I type `apt policy warzone2100 libglew2.0 libqt5core5a libqt5script5 libstdc++6` in the terminal, the result is shown below:

```
  Laptop@HP-DM1Z:~$ apt policy warzone2100 libglew2.0 libqt5core5a libqt5script5 libstdc++6
warzone2100:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 3.2.3-1~getdeb2~zesty
  Version table:
     3.2.3-1~getdeb2~zesty 500
        500 http://archive.getdeb.net/ubuntu zesty-getdeb/games amd64 Packages
     3.1.1-2 500
        500 http://ph.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
libglew2.0:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: (none)
  Version table:
libqt5core5a:
  Installed: 5.5.1+dfsg-16ubuntu7.5
  Candidate: 5.5.1+dfsg-16ubuntu7.5
  Version table:
 *** 5.5.1+dfsg-16ubuntu7.5 500
        500 http://ph.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     5.5.1+dfsg-16ubuntu7 500
        500 http://ph.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
libqt5script5:
  Installed: 5.5.1+dfsg-2build1
  Candidate: 5.5.1+dfsg-2build1
  Version table:
 *** 5.5.1+dfsg-2build1 500
        500 http://ph.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
libstdc++6:
  Installed: 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4
  Candidate: 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4
  Version table:
 *** 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4 500
        500 http://ph.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     5.3.1-14ubuntu2 500
        500 http://ph.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
Laptop@HP-DM1Z:~$
```

Comment: What Ubuntu release version are you using and what does `apt policy warzone2100 libglew2.0 libqt5core5a libqt5script5 libstdc++6` say? Please [edit] your question to provide the output.

Comment: Thank you for looking into this. I have updated my question to provide more details.

Comment: There we have the problem, you have a repository for Zesty enabled (archive.getdeb.com) which contains packages in versions that are incompatible with the rest of your system. You need to disable that repository, update your software lists and then it should get the correct version. Could you please add the output of `grep -r --include "*.list" "^deb" /etc/apt/sources.list* | grep -i zesty` to find out in which file the wrong repo is configured?

Comment: Your advice worked. I removed the repository you mentioned and I was able to install the game. Thank you! I also typed `grep -r --include "*.list" "^deb" /etc/apt/sources.list* | grep -i zesty` in the terminal as you asked, but it didn't do anything.

Comment: Cool. I posted the solution as answer so that you can accept it by clicking the grey round check button on its left. That way you mark your question as solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a repository for Zesty enabled (archive.getdeb.com) which contains packages in versions that are incompatible with the rest of your system. You need to disable that repository, update your software lists and then it should get the correct version.

- To disable the repository, either find its line in `/etc/apt/sources.list` or any file in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` and delete it or comment it out by putting a `#` in front of the line. Note that you need `sudo` to edit these files.

  You could also do it through the *System Settings → Software & Updates* GUI.
- Update your software lists using `sudo apt update`.
- Try to install your package again: `sudo apt install warzon2100`. It should pick a compatible version now and you shouldn't get any more conflicts.